# Xpath. Using fn:collection() and fn:base-uri() for getting URI of JSON-files

Tags: json, xml, xpath, xslt, saxon

I have a folder with several json-files (.json). The task is to get the uri for each json-files in the folder. I use fn:collection and fn:base-uri fo this in xslt-file. But I get an error when I execute fn:base-uri.

Error massage: "The required item type of the first argument of fn:base-uri() is node(); the supplied value map{(:size 55:)} is a map"

I tried the following code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enAPD.png)

It works for .xml-files (when you change the extension to .xml), but it doesn't work for json-files...
I have the following error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Bsm.png)

Maybe anyone knows the way how can I get uri for json-files.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 1):

Use `fn:uri-collection()` to get the URIs of the files in the collection, then access them individually using `fn:json-doc()`. Once parsed, the maps and arrays output by the JSON parser have no notion of identity, and contain no trace of where they came from.